# Updating mySQL INT with new INT

Tags: php, mysql, database, dice

Okay so for a basic outline I'm trying to update a column in my mySQL database dependent on the outcome of my code.

Basically it's rolling dice, if you beat the house it increases your INT by 5 if you loose to the house, it decreases by 5. This is for my own educational purposes and will not be used publicly.

The part that isn't working is the mysq_query("UPDATE") with both win and lose.

```
if (isset($_POST['roll'])) {
    $rand = rand(1, 6);
    $rand1 = rand(1, 6);
    $rand2 = rand(1, 6);
    $rand3 = rand(1, 6);
    $score = $rand + $rand1;
    $score1 = $rand2 + $rand3;

    echo 'You rolled a '.$rand.' and a '.$rand1.' Totalling '.$score;?><br><?
    echo 'Your opponent rolled a '.$rand2.' and a '.$rand3.' Totalling '.$score1;?><br><br><?
    if ($score > $score1){
        echo 'Win';
        $coins = $user_data['coins'] + 5;
        mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `coins` = '$coins' WHERE `user_id` = $user_id");
    } else {
        echo 'Loose';
        $coins1 = $user_data['coins'] - 5;
        mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `coins` = '$coins1' WHERE `user_id` = $user_id");
    }
}           
?>  
<form action="playdice.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="roll" value="Roll Dice.">
</form>
```

Comment: It's best if you supply the relevant error message or output of the code in question. Otherwise, we can't help you.

Comment: It doesn't give an error message, nor is any logged in the ftp. It just doesn't update the column for some reason.

Comment: add/substract in SQL e.g. `UPDATE users SET coins = coins-5 WHERE user_id = $user_id`, and `coins = coins+5` .. and do fetch the error then?

Comment: have you included the connect file ?

Comment: it echo win or loose ?

Comment: your not checking for error messages, so no surprise you don't see one. Add `mysql_error()`

Comment: Tried with the +/-5 in the Update and it still doesn't update the value. I'll try with what you say now Dagon. Also, it is connected otherwise I wouldn't be able to retreive $user_data['coins'];

Comment: @user2305310 - See my edited answer, I believe it solves the problem.

Comment: After checking with mysql_error() I get [ [21-Apr-2013 15:09:03] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: user_id in /home4/shamefac/public_html/lr/playdice.php on line 29 ]

Comment: then $user_id is not defined ,look where it defined, so when it defined your code will work.

Comment: You probably need to do a `$user_id = $user_data['id'];`

Comment: Thanks everyone, I needed to call $user_data['user_id'] like you say Oshawott.. Errors in my fatigue ;) Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the `'` around `$coins`. Those specify that the input is a `CHAR`, so MySQL is probably trying to insert a `CHAR` and refusing as it's an `INT` column.

You also don't appear to have defined a connection to query on.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
...
if ($score > $score1){
    echo "Win";
    $coins = $user_data['coins'] + 5;
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE `users` SET `coins` = $coins WHERE `user_id` = $user_id");
} else {
    echo "Lose";
    $coins = $user_data['coins'] - 5;
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE `users` SET `coins` = $coins WHERE `user_id` = $user_id");
}
```

This should work. (Sorry for switching you from the deprecated `mysql` syntax but I honestly don't remember it, if you're learning you're better off using `mysqli` anyway).

Comment: I've tried removing them after posting this, it still doesn't update. If I echo my $coins / $coins1 it shows them as the number I need it to, but it doesn't update in the database.

Comment: @user2305310 - Edited my answer, assumed something I shouldn't have.

Answer (score 1):

Put a `'` around the `$user_id`, it's probably a string. removing the quote tells MySQL that it is an integer.